# Strange behavior of toLocaleString() method

Tags: javascript, date, locale, string-formatting

I am little bit confused with strange behavior of `toLocaleString` method. Can someone to help to fix it please.

For example next code works correct:

```js
let value = "2018-11-26T10:00:00.000Z";
let dateValue = new Date(value).toLocaleString('ru-RU');
console.log(dateValue); // return: 26.11.2018, 16:00:00
```

This code return strange result:

```js
let value = "2018-11-26T10:00:00.000Z";
let dateValue = new Date(value);
let newDateValue = dateValue.setMonth(dateValue.getMonth() + 1).toLocaleString('ru-RU');
console.log(newDateValue); // return: 1 545 818 400 000
```

I expected that result would be `26.12.2018, 16:00:00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of [`setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) is a number, not a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Just use the mutated `dateValue` instead:

```js
let value = "2018-11-26T10:00:00.000Z";
let dateValue = new Date(value);

dateValue.setMonth(dateValue.getMonth() + 1);

let newDateValue = dateValue.toLocaleString('ru-RU');

console.log(newDateValue); // return: 26.12.2018, 16:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for this example!